# gradle adding -source.jar to war

Tags: gradle, ivy

I am in the process of converting a number of projects from ant+ivy to Gradle.

One of the projects (`address`) produces a simple jar for inclusion into a webapp.  I have set up the build.gradle to publish the jar and a sources jar to my private ivy repository.

`address/build.gradle` excerpt:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'publishing'
apply plugin: 'ivy-publish'

[...snip...]

task sourceJar(type: Jar) {
    from sourceSets.main.java
    classifier "source"
}

publishing {
    repositories {
        ivy {
            url 'http://dev.example.com/ivy/'
            layout "pattern", {
                artifact "[organisation]/[module]/[type]s/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"
            }
        }
    }
    publications {
        ivy(IvyPublication) {
            from components.java
            artifact(sourceJar) {
                type "source"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I publish this with `gradlew publish`.  My webapp then has a dependency on the resulting jar:

```
compile 'com.example:address:1.0.0'
```

The problem I have is that when I do `gradlew build` on the webapp, **the war's WEB-INF/lib includes `address-source-1.0.0.jar` along with the expected `address-1.0.0.jar`.**

I cannot figure out why the source jar is being included in the war.  It does not show up in `gradlew dependencies`.

Here is the ivy.xml being generated for the jar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:m="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/maven">
  <info organisation="com.example" module="address" revision="1.0.0" status="integration" publication="20141027154452"/>
  <configurations>
    <conf name="default" visibility="public" extends="runtime"/>
    <conf name="runtime" visibility="public"/>
  </configurations>
  <publications>
    <artifact name="address" type="jar" ext="jar" conf="runtime"/>
    <artifact name="address" type="source" ext="jar" conf="runtime" m:classifier="source"/>
  </publications>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-asm" rev="3.0.5.RELEASE" conf="runtime-&gt;default"/>
    <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-beans" rev="3.0.5.RELEASE" conf="runtime-&gt;default"/>
    <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-context" rev="3.0.5.RELEASE" conf="runtime-&gt;default"/>
    <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-expression" rev="3.0.5.RELEASE" conf="runtime-&gt;default"/>
    <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-core" rev="3.0.5.RELEASE" conf="runtime-&gt;default"/>
    <dependency org="log4j" name="log4j" rev="1.2.14" conf="runtime-&gt;default"/>
    <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="jcl-over-slf4j" rev="1.5.6" conf="runtime-&gt;default"/>
    <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-log4j12" rev="1.5.6" conf="runtime-&gt;default"/>
    <dependency org="commons-lang" name="commons-lang" rev="2.4" conf="runtime-&gt;default"/>
    <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-api" rev="1.5.6" conf="runtime-&gt;default"/>
  </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is that the source artifact is published in the *runtime* configuration as well, if you use a special configuration (e.g. *sources*) it should work:

```
publications {
  ivyJava(IvyPublication) {
    from components.java
    configurations.create('sources')
    artifact(sourceJar) {
      conf "sources"
    }
  }
}
```

(`configurations.create()` is needed because of 
[GRADLE-3162](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-3162))